# add custom claims to external oAuth provder

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, single-sign-on, identityserver4

Currently we are using an external oAuth provider for authentication and its a SSO so the user can login to our posrtal and other posrtal within the organization with same token. The problem is our posrtal has some specific claims like userId,etc (specific to our application). and we want these info to be in the token as well our oAuth prover is not allowing. Are there any other clean ways to solve this issue?

some solutions are

- API side we can check the sub and map to our own ID's by reading DB everytime a request comes into our endpoins
- cache the token and get the values

caceh is not a good idea and reading from DB everytime is also not a good idea. Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Comment: Why is caching not a good idea, why is doing a database query not a good idea?

Comment: @Evert the cache server is shared for us and data can be minipulated. database quesry not a good idea because every request I neeed to call DB which slows down the request time

Answer (score 1):

An authorization server should be able to look up custom claims at the time of token issuance, eg by calling an API endpoint that you provide. If you can't do this I would question your choice of authorization server.

An alternative is to validate the JWT, read its claims, then look up extra claims before producing the ClaimsPrincipal, then cache the extra claims. This is a less secure design though, so only use it when you have to. For an example, see [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts#L30).

Comment: Let me take a look at it and get back. Thanks.